# Better bail behavior in face of bug, Mac OS development

Tags: xcode, macos

When I'm writing a program for the iPhone, what the apple environment does when something goes wrong (from "unrecognized selector" to anything else), the app crashes and at the console, I have this meaningless stack debug spew that looks like this:

```
2009-12-19 11:57:37.843 ModelsProg[394:207] Stack: (
    30884955,
    2431960329,
    31266875,
    30836342,
    30688962,
    10115,
    2721311,
    2759178,
    2747272,
    2729683,
    2756789,
    38981329,
    30669696,
    30665800,
    2723433,
    2760707,
    9948,
    9802
)
```

Honestly I can't think of a more **useless** way to try and help a developer track the bug.    It doesn't even tell you what line the problem is from, unless [394:207] is some cryptic indication of where the bug happened.

How can I:

- Have the mac development environment tell me line number error and file occurred
- Suppress the meaningless stack chatter or change it to __actual function names__ as output, like Python's crashing bug output looks.

Comment: I've been developing Mac software for many years and I have never seen a stack trace that looked anything like that. What exactly are you doing?

Comment: This is iPhone development in XCode, and this is the output from the console after a crashing bug.

Comment: Yeah, I gathered that. What you need to answer is questions like "are you running an executable that has debug symbols in it?" and "do you get the same kind of output when debugging the example applications?"

Comment: This is after clicking "Build and Run" in XCode.

Comment: That's not really an answer to either question. Do you know how to find the debugger or would this be your first time launching Xcode?

Comment: Often, there is more than one line of output in the console when bad things happen.  Back up one line and there is probably an uncaught exception error log....

Comment: It is being built and launched in Debug mode.

Answer (score 1):

You are running a binary without symbols (a Release binary, probably) **or** the crash is happening in a spot where the crashtrace mechanism can't get to the symbols (like an uncaught exception).   Those #s are the addresses that would normally be looked up to produce a symbol.

Generally, for a stack spew like that, there is an uncaught exception log message on the line immediately before the spew.  *That* is generally going to give you just about all the information you need.

However, if you *do* need to symbolicate the stack trace, there are a couple of ways to do so.

If you are in `gdb`, you can use `info symbol 30884955` (obviously, substitute various numbers) to get a hold of more information about the symbol at that address in the stack trace.  `info line *30884955` is likely to produce even more useful results.

The key, though, is that you need the symbol files somewhere accessible. From Xcode, they should just be there (unless you have broken the symbol generation configuration of your app).   Otherwise, you would need to load them using the `symbol-file` command.

If you want to automate this or do symbolication outside of gdb, use the `atos` command.

Comment: "crashtrace mechanism can't get to symbols" - hmm!  This ALWAYS happens whenever I crash an objective-c program from XCode.

The way you suggested to track down the error source seems awfully manual.  What are "symbol files"?

Comment: Symbol files are the bits that the compiler writes to correlate executable to source. See documentation.  You still haven't indicated what the exception is;  that you are under Debug indicates that you have the ability to set a breakpoint on the exception raise.  See documentation again (or google).